# Loading wrong url in UIWebView from sidebar menu

Tags: ios, json, swift, uiwebview, alamofire

I am trying to load an url in UIWebView based on selected row in sidebar menu. For menu I am using SWRevealViewController and I am loading the menu with JSON using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON. It has 3 rows and an url for each row. My code for menu looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var valueToPass = String()
    var jsonArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "my-JSON-URL").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

            if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["items"].arrayObject {
                self.jsonArray = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
            }
            if self.jsonArray.count > 0 {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        print(self.jsonArray)
    }
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (jsonArray.count)
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DynamicCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let array = jsonArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = array["name"] as? String
    return cell
}
```

And I segue from this View Controller like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
    var array = jsonArray[indexPath]
    let url = array["url"] as? String
    valueToPass = url!
    print(valueToPass)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
    if (segue.identifier == "showDetail") {
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let targetController = viewController.topViewController as! DetailViewController
        targetController.passedValue = valueToPass
    }

}
```

And this is my code in DetailViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

var passedValue = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
    let url = NSURL (string: passedValue)
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
}
}
```

The problem is that when I select any row in menu for the first time, DetailViewController will appear blank. When i select any row second time it gives me the first url, third time - second url and so on. It is not based on which row I select, although the print(valueToPass) in didSelectRowAtIndexPath in MenuTableViewController prints right urls for each cell.

Answer (score 1):

It is because alamofire is `Asynchronous` and loads in the background thread while your webView is not loaded at all. Hence the empty page for the first time and so on. I suggest you write the `Request` in another function with a completion handler and call it in `viewDidLoad()` like so:

```
 func loadURL(url: String, completion: (isDone: Bool) -> ()){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url)...
    // code
if self.jsonArray.count > 0 {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
       completion(isDone: true)
        print(self.jsonArray)
    }
    }
```

And then in `viewDidLoad()` call it like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 loadUrl("Your Url here") { success in
if success{
 self.tableView.reloadData()
}
else{

}
}
```

Should fix your problem. Try! :)

Comment: I tried it, but it is still the same. But I realised, that when I select a row once and then select the same row second time, then it gives me right content in UIWebView